# Why doesn't my makefile create a debug folder after a release build?

Tags: makefile

I have a makefile building my project.

It builds fine when called with `make`, but if I try and do a `make debug` afterwards, it doesn't even attempt to create the debug output directory, which means the linking fails, even if I call `make clean` in between builds.

The debug build does work if I delete the "release" folder however.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Makefile

```
EXEC_DIR = ../../../../Bin/linux/release/
EXECUTABLE = $(EXEC_DIR)/prog
CC = g++
DEBUG = -g -D_DEBUG

...

CFLAGS = -Wall -c $(INCLUDE_DIRS) -std=c++11
LFLAGS = -Wall

...

all : $(EXECUTABLE)

debug : EXEC_DIR = ../../../../Bin/linux/debug/
debug : EXECUTABLE = $(EXEC_DIR)/prog
debug : CFLAGS += $(DEBUG)
debug : LFLAGS += $(DEBUG)
debug : $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE) : $(OBJS) | $(EXEC_DIR)
    $(CC) $(LFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXEC_DIR) :
    mkdir -p $(EXEC_DIR)

...

clean :
    -rm *.o *~
```

Comment: the line `debug : EXEC_DIR = ../../../../Bin/linux/debug/` does not do what you think it does.  What it does, is it sets `EXEC_DIR` only for the scope of the `debug` target (not globally for the makefile).

Comment: Even if that did work as expected `make` still wouldn't rebuild anything *other* than the executable since none of the source files will have changed.

Comment: But more to the point the value of `EXEC_DIR` set for the `debug` target isn't in effect during the `debug : EXECUTABLE = ` assignment line. That's the issue. Look at the output of `make -p` for the `debug` target to see that.

Comment: OK. Thank you guys, I'm taking a different approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what you're doing is creating a [Target Variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html), which is only effective in the scope of the `debug` recipes (not its sub-recipes).   What you likely want to do is have lines as follow:

```
ifeq ($(filter debug,$(MAKECMDGOALS)),debug)
    EXEC_DIR = ../../../../Bin/linux/debug/
    OBJ_DIR = ../../../../Bin/linux/debug/objs
    ...
endif
```

and then prepend `$(OBJ_DIR)` to all of your object files.   This gets around the not rebuilding source files that Etan was mentioning.

Comment: So should this be at the start of the file, after declaring `EXEC_DIR` and `OBJ_DIR` normally for the release build?

Comment: Either at the start of a file with an else, or after the other declarations (as the last declaration will take precedence)

Comment: How do I invoke this then?